# Child props is null when loading component from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to React - so bear with me.

I'm trying to create a set of authentication protected routes/components. I have the below code that I am using to achieve that.

However, my issue is that when the child component loads, the `userInfo` is `{}` (i.e. not set). I know that the `userInfo` is being returned from the `userService` as my `console.log` returns the correct data.

Am I going about this right? I want to be able to protect a component/route, and pass through the `userInfo` to any protected route so I can do stuff with the data in the respective component.

```
const UserAuthenticatedRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});

    useEffect(async () => {
        const r = await userService.isUserLoggedIn();
        console.log(r.status);

        if (r.status === 200){
            setIsLoggedIn(true);
            const userInfo = await r.json();
            console.log(userInfo);
            setUserInfo(userInfo);
        } else {
            setIsLoggedIn(false);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <Route {...rest}  render={props => (
            <>
                <main>
                    {isLoggedIn &&
                        <Component {...props} userInfo={userInfo}/>
                    }
                </main>
            </>
        )}
        />
    );
};
```

Comment: you shouldn't `setIsLoggedIn(true)` until after the `await`, so the child is never rendered until you actually have the user data

Comment: Thanks @RobinZigmond that did the trick :)